# Sprite added in pixi flicker at 0,0 coordinate for a sec

Tags: sprite, flicker, pixi.js

I am using pandajs framework, so when I add a sprite to a container, the container is already added to stage before, the sprite flickers for a sec at 0,0 coordinate and then repositions itself to where it should have

```
var sprite = new game.Sprite("fly_ladybird");
sprite.rotation = Math.PI;
sprite.pivot.y = sprite.height;
sprite.pivot.x = sprite.width;
this.grid.addChild(sprite);
sprite.position.set(x - sprite.width / 2, y - sprite.height / 2);
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are adding sprite to the stage before you positioned it.

```
sprite.position.set(x - sprite.width / 2, y - sprite.height / 2);
this.grid.addChild(sprite);
```

Which means that sprite will be added to default position (0, 0). If however you are performing this action in the loop which might as well be the case. Then you will see flickering effect. Because sprite will position itself to default position then move to position you wanted it to be in the first place. However, on the new position you wouldn't notice it because there are already sprites with the same texture.